# Activating Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure returns "Column Limit Exceeded"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting the following error when attempting to activate the Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure. There are only about 140 columns defined in the entire site collection.

I had previously activated and subsequently deactivated this feature. I don't know whether this might be causing the problem. But I really have no idea.

I am a developer and this is my first question on serverFault. Please be gentle.

Error Message:

> Column Limit Exceeded.
>
> There are too many columns of the
> specified data type. Please delete
> some other columns first. Note that
> some column types like numbers and
> currency use the same data type.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
> SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
> 2ec9ae3a-5464-4922-9760-874099f51420
>
> Date and Time: 11/8/2010 3:43:44 PMDate and Time: 11/8/2010 3:43:44 PM

Comment: Since you say Sharepoint Foundation, I guess that indicates you are using Sharepoint 2010 here.

Answer (score 1):

Haydar,

There are limits on the number of columns by data type, which is apparently what you're running up against.

I found a table listing the per data type limitations on SharePoint lists as well as the size of each column type [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column) (scroll down to the **Column Limits** section).  Aside from the individual data type limits, the sum total of all columns in a SharePoint 2010 list cannot exceed 8,000 bytes.

As far as why you would have been able to enable this previously, I'm not entirely sure.

(I realize this is about 4 months late, but hopefully it will help someone)